# Ubuntu from external Hard Drive Error

Tags: installation, boot, windows-7, external-hdd

I've previously installed Ubuntu 13.10 with the "USB Universal Installer" into a 4gb USB, and it worked fine. Now I want it to be in my old computers Hard Drive so I can save the files and use it as if it were the real Operating System. I'm using it as an external HDD.

I followed the same steps than with USB (Download the ISO and then Using USB universal Installer made it bootable) but when I try to go into Ubuntu (after selecting Ubuntu as the system I'd like to use) this appears:

```
Windows found a communication problem with a device connected to the equipment.
The cause of this error may be the disconnection of the external device while in use, or the hardware is defective.
If you keep getting this error message please get in touch with the manufacturer of the hardware.
File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
State:\ 0xc00000e9
Information: Unexpected E/S error
```

[that's what it says, its not exactly the same since I had to translate it]
Can anyone help me out with this, I really don't know if I had to do the same than with a USB, looked in all the forums but got even more confused as I read(new at all of this).

What does it mean, and if I did not install it correctly, how do I do it?

PS: The hard drive was always connected to the computer.